# VBA using wildcard to attach word docx

Tags: vba, outlook, wildcard, email-attachments

I'm trying to come up with a code to attach a file based on the email requirements. The file name structure is consistant - Date(YY-MM-DD) followed by a unique number which begins with E and a varying description. Example: "17-08-10 E****** file description.docx". The file being attached will have the unique identifier mentioned in the email body.

I've pieced together codes that i found in my search but i still can't figure out it doesn't attach my document.

Here is my code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim EmailBody As String

Dim Mail_worksheet As Worksheet
Dim Mail_worksheet1 As Worksheet
Set Mail_worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Set Mail_worksheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send")

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strName As String

Dim c As Integer
Dim d As String

d = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4)

EmailBody = "<body style=""font-family:Calibri;font-size:16"">Hi," & "<br><br>" & _
            "Document attached for:" & "<br><br>"
                On Error Resume Next
                    For c = 0 To d - 1
                    If Mail_worksheet.Cells(15, 2 + c) = Mail_worksheet1.Cells(7, 6) And Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + c) Like "E*" Then
                    EmailBody = EmailBody & Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + c) & "<br>"

                        strPath = "D:\My Documents\"      'Edit to your full path
                        strName = Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + c) 
                        strFilter = "*.docx"
                        strFile = Dir(strPath & Format(Date, "YY-MM-DD") & strName & strFilter)

                        While (strFile <> "")
                        If InStr(strFile, "") > 0 Then 'i think my problem is in this line, i'm not sure what to make of it.
                        newItem.Attachments.Add (strPath & strFile)
                        End If
                        strFile = Dir
                        Wend

                    End If
                    Next c

            EmailBody = EmailBody & "<br>Thank you." & "<br><br>" & _
                        "Best regards," 

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "Word doc for product - " & Format(Date, "DD MMM YYYY")
    .HTMLBody = EmailBody

    .Display

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: On Error Resume Next without matching On Error Goto 0 is the worst error in all programming. Remove the one just before For c = 0 To d - 1. If there is no error great, otherwise update the question with the new code, the error, and the line that generated the error.

Comment: Oh, thanks for spotting that. May i know what's the issue if there wasn't the matching On Error Goto 0? Can't tell as it had worked fine. I removed the On Error Resume Next anyway and it works fine. Do you know how to do the wildcard attachment?

Comment: "... the most commonly used and misused form.  It instructs to VBA to essentially ignore the error and resume execution on the next line of code. It is very important to remember that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error. It simply instructs VBA to continue as if no error occured. However, the error may have side effects,"
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: With Option Explicit at the top you should find a problem with newitem

Comment: Does this format allow me to attach a document? Considering that its before the Outmail portion.

Comment: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) precedes newItem.Attachments.Add so just change to OutMail.Attachments.Add  You may find you need to remove  .HTMLBody = EmailBody  so the body with the attachment is not overwritten by EmailBody.  After this you might be close to a good question for this site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, managed to figure this out. Had to create new integers for this part to work.

```
For a = 0 To b - 1
    If Mail_worksheet.Cells(15, 2 + a) = Mail_worksheet1.Cells(7, 6) And Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + a) Like "E*" Then
        strPath = "D:\My Documents\"
        strName = "*" & Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + a).Value & "*.docx"
        strFile = Dir(strPath & strName)

        Do While Len(strFile) > 0

        OutMail.Attachments.Add strPath & strFile
        strFile = Dir
        Loop
    End If

    Next a
```

Thanks niton for your guidance!